# change Item text color of NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigationview

How can i change NavigationView menu item text color.My menu.xml file is, i also write

> app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
>           app:itemTextColor="@color/white" in my layout but it will not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:checked="false"
    android:title="@string/popular">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/tag1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/bird"
            android:title="@string/tag1" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tag2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/rabbit"
            android:title="@string/tag2" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tag3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/bird"
            android:title="@string/tag3" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tag4"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/rabbit"
            android:title="@string/tag4" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/tag5"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/bird"
            android:title="@string/tag5" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting"
            android:title="@string/setting" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/rating"
            android:title="@string/rate" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

[image: Here is my NavigationView in my app as you can see there is no any effects if itemTextColor]

my NavigationView like..

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/theme_primary"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

Comment: But item color is white which u are using in xml. then what is problem?

Comment: As u can see in my  NavigationView image my popular tag is still black color that's the main problem,i want popular text in white color .

Comment: Probably TextView in inside layout_drawer_header layout so try to check it

Comment: as per your response we can not change color of Menu item color am i right ?

Comment: you can change secondary color of your app, that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the response, i just search little and i found the answer there is no any style changes, i just change in JAVA file like and it's done.

```
NavigationView navigation_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigation_view.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK));
    navigation_view.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationView` uses the color of `Widget.Design.NavigationView` theme.
You can override that theme like following.

Create your own style which overrides`Widget.Design.NavigationView` in your style.xml:

```
<style name="NavigationStyle" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Use that theme in your layout xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        android:theme="@style/NavigationStyle"
        ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

also you can add style for navigation item.
`

```
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#4dffffff</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/white_with_alpha</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>

</style>`
```